# What is the best way to create file folder for specifi user in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a simple dashboard in which users can register and do some stuff, now I would like to generate a file with username and his id; something like `widget/obama2030.js` in Laravel when a user is registered

my app structure:

myapp

```
-app
-bootstrap
-database
-resource
 .....
-widget
 -------
```

in my user registration controller, I have the following.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
   
    File::makeDirectory('/widget/'.$user->name.Auth::user()->id, 0755, true);

    return $user;
}
```

Now when user click the button register I am getting the following error

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object
```

what is wrong with my code????

Comment: 1) What line does that refer to? 2) Why even do this? Creating per-user files is typically a bad idea. You want to make an endpoint using PHP will will dynamically serve the expected data, it doesn't need to physically exist as a file.

Comment: @deceze I need this file to insert it  to user table as URL, later on, this file will contain some user configurations

Comment: Yeah… again, it doesn't need to be a *physical file*, now does it?

Comment: doesn't, so how do I solve my problem so that each user can have his/her own file url like /widget/obama212.js in a user table?

Comment: You want that when a browser requests the URL `/widget/...js` to output something that's specific to that user, *right*?! Well, how do you implement something like a user profile page, or any other regular Laravel page that outputs something specific to the currently logged in user, or otherwise something user-specific? You don't create a bunch of separate HTML files, *right*? You have a Laravel controller and view that you dynamically generate from info from the database, or whatever. **Same thing.**

Comment: this file will contain another application as a widget , why do this? I want a user to be able to copy the URL and use it on their website,

Comment: It. Still. Doesn't. Need. To. Be. A. Physical. File. Think in terms of HTTP and server requests to URLs and responses to those. None of the URLs on a server need to exist as physical files. The most sensible thing would probably be to have *one* actual .js file which every user puts into their website, and that then makes an *AJAX* call to your server to fetch some user specific information.

Answer (score 2):

You've created a user, but you haven't logged them in as that newly created user.

As such, `Auth::user()` is null, and `(null)->id` won't work.

After creating your user, log them in:

```
Auth::login($user)
```

and your code should work.

That said, it's typically not necessary (and it's quite messy) to actually create files for each user - you can almost certainly handle this via a Laravel route, instead.

Comment: Thanks but now when I check inside folder widget is empty?

Comment: @user9964622 What else did you expect `File::makeDirectory` to do? It makes a directory. That's it.

Comment: I mean the code above does not create a directory at all and there is no errors

Comment: @user9964622 You probably created it at the server's root because you set the path to `'/widget/'`.

Comment: so if I want the folder to apear the same as app or database folder apears how do I do that?

Comment: @user9964622 As deceze is trying to tell you, **this isn't really a good approach**. There are better ways of accomplishing what you want with Laravel's routing. That said, you'd want to use something like `storage_path()` for your paths.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` isn't returning anything, so it flakes out when you try and access `->id`